# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but

Tags: php, android-studio, localhost, retrofit2

I have a big problem with work in Retrofit Library in Android Studio,
when I create a PHP file for get something or post something to database and work on JSON that back from API, everything is ok when I work with localhost, BUT when I upload that PHP files to real host I get this error in Android Studio:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

For example:

This is my interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("checkuser.php")
Call<chechExistsUser> checkUserExists(@Field("phone") String phone);
```

This is retrofit class:

```
public class Retrofit_Tools {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(String baseUrl) {

        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                            .setLenient()
                            .create()))
            .build();
        }
        return retrofit;


    }
}
```

and this is Common class that I get in any activity class:

```
public class Common {
    private static final String baseUrl="http://192.168.56.1/drinkshop1/";
    //private static final String baseUrl="http://reza-ghahremani.zili.ir/drinkshop/";


    public static Retrifit_Interface getApi(){
        return Retrofit_Tools.getRetrofit(baseUrl).create(Retrifit_Interface.class);
    }
}
```

and I use this code in any activity:

```
Retrifit_Interface retrofit=Common.getApi();
```

finally i can use any method in interface:

```
retrofit.checkUserExists(etPhone.getText().toString().trim()).enqueue(new Callback<chechExistsUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<chechExistsUser> call, Response<chechExistsUser> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.body().error_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<chechExistsUser> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }
        });
```

If the problem is about PHP files or API, why everything is ok in localhost?
why every thing is ok in localhost and does not work in realhost?

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: everything is ok in localHost

Comment: Are you running the same versions of PHP on localhost and the server?

Comment: how can I find it?

Comment: Use the `phpversion()` function.

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago a friend had a very similar problem *if not the same*. We found out that Retrofit needed a square bracket surrounding the json. For example a json like this:

```
{  
  "data":{  
     "info1":"something here"
    }
}
```

Should be converted to this:

```
[{
  "data":{  
    "info1":"something here"
 }
}]
```

Maybe this can solve you problem